# SAP HANA - Smart Data Integration (Twitter) - Error while running procedures

Tags: twitter, procedure, hana

Currently I am trying to perform a Twitter analysis with SAP HANA. I want to load Twitter data using the Twitter API. I already configured the Twitter adapter for the SAP HANA system (I configurated a remote source for the Twitter adapter). I also created a *.hdbreptask file which in turn creates the procedure.

First time I called the procedure, everything worked fine. Twitter data was loaded into the table.

Here the problem begins. If I want to run the procedure a second time, I got an error message:

> (SQL Editor) Could not execute 'CALL "Twitter.twitterdata::twitter_allsynonyms.START_REPLICATION"()'
> Error: (dberror) 129 - transaction rolled back by an internal error: [129]
> "Twitter.twitterdata::twitter_allsynonyms.START_REPLICATION": line 3 col 0 (at pos 160): [129] (range 3): transaction rolled back by an internal error: sql processing error: QUEUE: Twitter.twitterdata::twitter_allsynonyms.SUB_VTStatus: Cannot perform Queue on remote subscription Twitter.twitterdata::twitter_allsynonyms.SUB_VTStatus. It is not in created state. Reset state using ALTER RESET to perform Queue.
> : line 1 col 1 (at pos 0)

Unfortunately, I do not understand this error message. How do I run the procedure a second time, so that I can add new data?

Thank you very much in advance,
Jean

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly your procedure does. It looks like it sets up a [REMOTE SUBSCRIPTION](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.00/en-US/12d89b67c7994f80bc516e30dadd3c0a.html) and puts it into  QUEUE and finally DISTRIBUTE mode. In order to run the procedure again, the error message tells you to rest the subscription.

Try this:

```
ALTER REMOTE SUBSCRIPTION "Twitter.twitterdata::twitter_allsynonyms.SUB_VTStatus" RESET;
```

See [ALTER REMOTE SUBSCRIPTION](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.00/en-US/f88b70b3170849b0a57d4ff618887dce.html) documentation for details.

If the procedure even creates the remote subscription you will have to drop it to:

```
DROP SUBSCRIPTION "Twitter.twitterdata::twitter_allsynonyms.SUB_VTStatus";
```

See [DROP SUBSCRIPTION](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.00/en-US/af65fc25d26c4968ac1448cf13056432.html) documentation for more details.